# web3.py geth txpool help

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, web3.py, infura, txpool

I need to help accessing the geth.txpool API namespace in web3.py.

Heres what I do (for example):

```
from web3 import Web3

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/MY_KEY'))

txPool = web3.geth.txpool

print(txPool.status())
```

everytime I get:

```
ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method txpool_status does not exist/is not available'}
```

every method in the geth.txpool namespace return similar errors. Anybody know what Im doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an infura specific issue. I get the same error in web3 rust. Using my local full node fixes the issue.